# Выбор данных (года) в нужном формате посредством запроса

Tags: java, hibernate

В БД хранится `Timestamp`. Выборка происходит так:

```
    TreeSet<String> result = new TreeSet<>();
    try {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        List<Timestamp> timestampResult = new ArrayList<>();

        timestampResult = session.createQuery("select op.datopl from Oplata as op").list();

        SimpleDateFormat formatY = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
        timestampResult.forEach(val -> result.add(formatY.format(val)));  

        ...
```

Нужны только года. Можно ли выделить года запросом, без этих преобразований?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<Integer> years = session.createQuery("select year(op.datopl) from Oplata as op")
                             .list();
```

Comment: Даа, нужно учить SQL, хотя бы минимум... Спасибо.

Comment: Это HQL. Почитать можно [здесь](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-functions), например.